# Prevent scrollview from autoresizing

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

Im creating a basic messaging app with the message "bubbles" inside a scroll view. When the user first opens the screen the keyboard is not showing (besides an input box at the bottom), when they press the input box and start typing the keyboard with pop up (using NSNotificationCenter) a function will be called to resize the scrollview so that is no longer behind the keyboard.

That part all works well but when the user sends their message and a new bubble is added to the scrollview. The scrollview will automatically revert back to the size of the screen thus being behind the keyboard.

The scrollview is originally created in storyboard to take up the whole dimensions of the screen. So I suspect the cause of the resizing is due to some kind of message calling autolayout to update the scrollview when a subview is being added to it.

Im looking for a way to prevent the scroll view from reverting back to this autolayout when a subview is added to it, Thank you!

Comment: what you're looking to do Is probably more easily implemented using a tableview. that said, you could try implementing `layoutSubviews` and keep the frame of the scrollview in place, but also update the frame, visibleRect and/or the content offset. that said, there are libraries that do exactly this kind of messaging interface.

Comment: When you adjust the `UIScrollView`'s frame for the keyboard, do you do so via your constraint's constants?

Comment: @paulvs, im relatively new to storyboard so i didnt realise to it that way, i did exactly that nad it works perfect thank you!

Comment: I added my comment as an answer, if you're happy with it feel free to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the keyboard appears, adjust the `UIScrollView`'s size by modifying its constraint's constants.